# How to customize the error message for NoSuchElementException in Optional class

Tags: java, option-type

I have a method that throws `NotFoundException` if my object id is `null`.

```
public void removeStatementBundleService(String bundleId) throws NotFoundException {
    Optional<StatementBundle> bundleOpt = statementBundleRepository.findById(bundleId);

    if(bundleOpt.isPresent()) {
        StatementBundle bundle = bundleOpt.get();

        if(bundle.getStatements() != null && !bundle.getStatements().isEmpty()) {               
            for(Statement statement: bundle.getStatements()) {
                statementRepository.delete(statement);
            }
        }

        if(bundle.getFileId() != null) {
            try {
                fileService.delete(bundle.getFileId());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }

        statementBundleRepository.delete(bundle);

    } else {
        throw new NotFoundException("Statement bundle with id: " + bundleId + " is not found.");
    }
}
```

I found out that this isn't needed since the `java.util.Optional` class is used. In the oracle documentation I found out that if `get()` is used and there is no value then `NoSuchElementException` is thrown. What is the best way I can add my error message to the exception. I am trying to open the `Optional` class in Eclipse to try change inside it(not sure if this is good practice) but Eclipse will not let me access this class on the other hand I read that this class is also final.

Comment: I suggest a read on how to use ORM to delete all that stuff in one go instead of what you do no. That instead of abusing an optional like that.

Comment: What about [`Optional#orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When resolving the `Optional value`, you can directly **throw an Exception if the value is not present**:

```
Optional<StatementBundle> bundleOpt = statementBundleRepository.findById(bundleId);
StatementBundle bundle = bundleOpt.orElseThrow(() 
    -> new NotFoundException("Statement bundle with id: " + bundleId + " is not found.");
```

or (single statement):

```
StatementBundle bundle = statementBundleRepository.findById(bundleId)
    .orElseThrow(()
     -> new NotFoundException("Statement bundle with id: " + bundleId + " is not found.");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Optional` class does provide a `orElseThrow(...)` method which takes a `Supplier` as it's only parameter and therefore allowing us to throw custom exception in case the value is absent.

This enables expressions like:

```
StatementBundle bundle = bundleOpt.orElseThrow( ()->new NotFoundException("Statement bundle with id: " + bundleId + " is not found.") );
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't manipulate the `NoSuchElementException`, wrap it in a custom exception.

```
try {
    try {
        // We simulate a failing .get() on an Optional.
        throw new NoSuchElementException("message from Optional.get()");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        // We wrap the exception into a custom exception and throw this.
        throw new MyException("my message", ex);
    }
} catch (MyException ex) {
    // Now we catch the custom exception and can inspect it and the
    // exception that caused it.
    System.err.println(ex.getClass().getCanonicalName()
            + ": " + ex.getMessage()
            + ": " + ex.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

Output:

```
MyException: my message: message from Optional.get()
```